# Cassandra connection to Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am connecting spark with Cassandra and I am storing csv file in Cassandra, when I enter this command I got error.

```
 dfprev.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") .options(Map("keyspace"->"sensorkeyspace","table"->"sensortable")).save()
```

Then I got this error.

> java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:168)
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$8.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:154)
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:32)
>     at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.syncAcquire(RefCountedCache.scala:69)

Comment: Is 127.0.0.1 and port 9042 your cassandra connection?

Comment: I am using Cassandra 3.11.2 and spark 2.0.2 and scala version 2.11.8, would you tell me which connector I used.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you Cassandra listening on `localhost`?  You may need to configure the list of IP addresses of your Cassandra cluster by specifying `spark.cassandra.connection.host` setting in Spark configuration.  See [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md) for details.

Comment: 'import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark._'import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
org.apache.spark.SparkContext
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
 val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
 val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
 val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("sensorkeyspace", "sensortable")

Comment: When I enter the last line this gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

There might any one of the following

1. Cassandra server might not be running at 127.0.0.1:9042

   Please check the cassandra is listening at port 9042 using ***netstat -an*** command.
2. There might be dependency issues when fat jar.

   Please make sure that you have added right version of cassandra connector in library dependency like

   "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M3"

> I am running this command ./spark-shell --packages
>   com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3 --conf
>   spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.

The package to be specified as,

spark-shell --packages "com.datastax.spark":"spark-cassandra-connector_2.11":"2.0.0-M3"

Comment: I am new to Cassandra and spark I don't know what should I do.  Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042     I don't know how I remove this error

Comment: I am running this command ./spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Check these things, May solve your problem,
1. Find cqlsh.py file in your system by entering the below command in shell

```
 whereis cqlsh
```

2. Edit the cqlsh.py and change the DEFAULT PORT to your IP
3. Initiate spark context with the following SparkConfig()

   ```
     val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "<YOUR IP>")
     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   ```